# How can I build a Python module in Hy?

Tags: python, lisp, hy

I'd like to use [Hy](http://hylang.org), a dialect of Lisp on top of Python.  However my coworkers all use Python and aren't likely to switch over to a Lisp dialect any time soon.

How can I package Hy code into a standard Python module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have three basic options.

1. have your coworkers import hy as dg123 wrote.
2. use a python package and import hy yourself in your packages __init __.py file. Your coworkers can then just import your modules.
3. compile your module using hyc and deploy the .pyc file which your coworkers can import as normal python module.

Answer (score 5):

Simple! After all your coworkers have done `pip install hy`, they can include your `.hy` files as regular Python modules by:

1) Importing `hy`:

```
import hy
```

2) Importing the name of the module as if it were Python with a `.py` extension:

```
import module_name
```

(where in this example, `module_name` would be referring to `module_name.hy` in the same directory as the Python code)